# How to get the code coverage in Angular Dart?

Tags: testing, dart, code-coverage, angular-dart

I've tried using package `coverage` to get the code coverage from my Angular Dart 4.0 project.

The following steps are my working flow:

1. run `pub serve test --port=8081`
2. run `pub run test --pub-serve=8081 --pause-after-load`
3. waiting for test runner print the observatory URL (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:12345)
4. run `pub global run coverage:collect_coverage --port=12345 -o coverage.json`
5. press Enter to resume test runner
6. run `pub global run coverage:format_coverage --packages=.packages-c -i coverage.json -o coverage.report`

After step 5, I will get a `coverage.json` file which contains some data, but I don't know why the coverage report always shows each code is uncovered.

Am I using a wrong flow for getting code coverage? Or have any better way to do it?

Thanks !

---

There are my experiment code:

`experiment_component.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'experiment_component',
  template: '<h1>{{greeting}}</h1>'
)
class ExperimentComponent {

  String greeting = '';

  void greet() {
    greeting = 'Hello';
  }

}
```

`experiment_component_test.dart`:

```dart
@TestOn('browser')
@Tags(const ['aot'])
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular4_test/src/experiment_component.dart';
import 'package:angular_test/angular_test.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

NgTestBed<ExperimentComponent> testBed;
NgTestFixture<ExperimentComponent> testFixture;

@AngularEntrypoint()
void main() {
  tearDown(disposeAnyRunningTest);

  setUp(() async {
    testBed = new NgTestBed<ExperimentComponent>();
    testFixture = await testBed.create();
  });

  test('should render Hello', () async {
    await testFixture.update((comp)=> comp.greet());
    expect(testFixture.text, contains('Hello'));
  });
}
```

`.packages-c`:

```
angular4_test:lib/
```

`coverage.report`:

```dart
|import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
|
|@Component(
|  selector: 'experiment_component',
|  template: '<h1>{{greeting}}</h1>'
|)
|class ExperimentComponent {
|
|  String greeting = '';
|
|  void greet() {
0    greeting = 'Hello';
|  }
|
|}
```